# MYSQL Distinct Query on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, subquery

I want to select the data from the Food Table on userid but the foodname should be distinct.

I have used the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Food 
WHERE cfid IN (
    SELECT distinct(foodname) FROM Food WHERE userid=234
);
```

but it returns an empty set of data.

Food Table

```
cfid foodname            userid brand
 160 special chapati        234 homemade
 161 chicken fry special    234 kfc
 162 apple punch            234 homemade
 164 pohapokri              234 homemade
 165 pohapokri              234 homemade
 167 besan gatte            234 home made
 168 besan gatte            234 home made
 169 pohapokri              234 homemade
 172 chicken fry special    234 kfc
 174 special chapati        234 homemade
 175 special chapati        234 homemade
```

Comment: Of course, cfId can't be found in a distinct foodname list. What's your desired result ? You just need foodname, userid and brand ? If you need the cfId, which one do you want if it's a "duplicate" on foodname ?

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus i want  distinct foodname only   with cfid,userid,brand may be dublicate

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus  yes i need the  first cfid if  dublicate foodname is there

Comment: Your subquery returning a distinct food names. In your cfid column field u are storing ids. And you are assigning food names to id column. How this is possible... This always return empty result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, use a `group by` and a `min` on cfId

```
select min(cfId), foodname, userid, brand
from food
group by foodname, userid, brand
--where userid=234
```